# How to increase the height of navigation bar in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm working on a app, in which I need to keep a navigation bar.
when I write any title on the bar, the time and the title kinda get very close to each other. I wanted to increase the height of the bar, so it can get some breathing room.

Comment: r u used the storyboard or xib

Comment: I am using main.storyboard

Comment: There is very nice answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142375/changing-the-height-of-the-navigation-bar-ios-swift

Comment: Maybe you can use a custom view to replace the navigation bar.This is more flexible.

Answer (score 45):

select your **ViewController** --> select your **Navigation Item** --> **Prompt** --> Add **space** it **increase** the `height` of `**Navigation bar**`

Check Image here :
[image]

**Programatically**

Add this in **viewWillAppear** or **viewDidAppear**  method

**Objective-C**

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,80.0)];
```

**Swift**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 80.0)
```

**Swift-3**

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 80.0)
```

**iOS 11**

[image]

**objective C**

```
for (UIView *subview in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) containsString:@"BarBackground"]) {
        CGRect subViewFrame = subview.frame;
        // subViewFrame.origin.y = -20;
        subViewFrame.size.height = 100;
        [subview setFrame: subViewFrame];
    }
}
```

**swift**

```
for subview in (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
       if NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder).contains("BarBackground") {
            var subViewFrame: CGRect = subview.frame
            // subViewFrame.origin.y = -20;
            subViewFrame.size.height = 100
            subview.frame = subViewFrame

        }

    }
```

Comment: The moving the prompt with white text WORKS , not sure why but okay :D

Comment: Setting programatically in viewWillAppear does not work in iOS 10

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, bro your answer works for me but for collectionView Controller, the navigation bar position is back and Collection VC scroll View is front. How can I set navigation bar to front ?

Comment: @adev - check the updated answer, its working fine for me in iOS 11

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I meant the programmatically setting thing. I dont want to set the prompt since I cant adjust left and right barbutton items to keep it in middle. It looks weird without ability to adjust those buttons. I wanted to set it in code.

Comment: Still same result for me. Can you please try with left and right bar button items added too. Was it moving down when you do this?

Comment: is it also possible to animate the "growth" of the navbar? The transition to the bigger navbar is not smooth from one VC (with a small one) to the next

Comment: Works for me in iOS 11 as well as in iOS 10. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 18):

simply add this line to your viewController

```
navigationController?.additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = 30 
  // where 30 is the extra space, add as per your need.
```

Comment: In my case, I have to hide my statusBar.  So I did that by overriding view controllers method. It created a problem. When I was hiding status bar, my navbar was moving up and down when statusbar was unhidden. So I need to add space in place of statusbar. And this above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

Apple [proposes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html) not to resize `navigationBar` itself, but remove shadow from bar and add custom view under your `navigationBar`. This can work for most cases. Check Apple's samples.

Comment: Can you describe where you see that proposal? I can't find it in the page you linked.

Comment: @Patrick you need to download attached project. They have sample implementation.

Answer (score 12):

Add the following extension to your project:

```
import UIKit

extension UINavigationBar {

    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 80.0)
    }

}
```

Comment: How to call this extension?

Comment: @Hemang this method is automatically called when the UINavigationBars in your app are drawn. There's no need to call it by yourself.

Comment: This doesnt work in iOS 11. Even though it is getting called, nav bar still has old height.

Answer (score 12):

Please refer the apple recommended approach for extended navigation bar here,

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Link only answers can become useless if the link breaks. Please provide a minimal set of instructions in the post itself.

Comment: this link is Apple long term link and the best answer described here. Other answers are more hacks than convenient way to use nav bar and nav bar ctrl

Comment: ExtendedNavBar is not part of the sample Xcode project

Comment: The sample code pointed to by that link doesn't include an example of increasing the height.

Answer (score 11):

> **THIS SOLUTION NO LONGER WORKS IN Xcode 8.x.x and later!**

you can also increase height without creating the custom navigation follow the following steps

**Step 1 Selecte Navigation bar in Storyboard or XIB**

[image]

**Step 2 Copy ObjectID from Identity Inspector**

[image]

**Step 3 Open Storyboard/XIB as Source Code**

[image]

**Step 4 Find ObjectID in Source Code past ObjectID in search**

[image]

**Step 5 Edit height! thats all**

[image]

**I hope this will help you**

Comment: Is apple allow this ? please let me know

Comment: Works in xcode 8. Just search for `navigationBar` and set the height ;)

Comment: @MeghsDhameliya This is not working in Xcode 8.3.3 , Xcode 9, Xcode 9.2

Comment: @AshokLondhe oh i will update on note, thanks for update

Comment: why does editing the underlying XML of a visual editing tool as a solution have upvotes?

Answer (score 8):

Add this in **viewWillAppear** method

```
CGFloat height = 80;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
self.view.frame.size.width,height)];
```

if it increase first and shrinks to original height then add this code in **viewDidAppear** method

Comment: My suggestion is kindly use custom navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

We need to change the height of the navigation bar for each time the view show.So put the code on viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 80)
}
```

we can set the width as the width of the view and change the height as we wish.

Comment: the navigation bar frame is changed, but not working. iam using xcode12.2 with iphone6s14.2

Answer (score 1):

```
    navigationController?.additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = 25
```

Add this to viewDidLoad. it will definitely work. Successfully worked in Xcode 12-version

Comment: This updates the UINavigationController overall area, but the UINavigationBar remains at 44px.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the height of the default `NavigationBar` if I'm not wrong.

Although, you can create a custom `NavigationBar` and add a custom height to it.

Answer (score -4):

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setPrefersLargeTitles:YES];` 
is going to Increase the Navigation bar height Programmatically