# Custom height for UINavigationBar or alternative of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a viewController with navigation bar. I want to increase the height of navigation bar but I can't. I already search about increasing the height of navigation bar but not get any success.

Is there any to increase the height of navigation bar or any other lib/alternative?

Comment: can i know what you want to do with the custom height?

Comment: so i can suggest any way if exists?

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar I want to increase height of UINavigationBar custom height like 60.0f... default is 44.0f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your custom view as your navigation bar. Customize view as per your requirement and hide the default navigation bar as

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

You can give back action on the back button as

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You can perform the same action on button as well as touch of UIView or UIImageView as per your need. Hope it helps. Happy Coding.. !!

Answer (score 4):

Directly changes are not permissible

`... It is not permissible to change the navigation bar object or modify its bounds, frame, or alpha values directly...` by [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html)

But here are same questions and answers:

1. [Changing the height of the Navigation bar iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142375/changing-the-height-of-the-navigation-bar-ios-swift)
2. [Change UINavigationBar Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894985/change-uinavigationbar-height)

Answer (score 1):

The system's default height is 44.0f.

You can't change default height, but you can hide the navigation bar, then customize a view instead of system's navigation bar.