# Set navigations bar height in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, height, uinavigationbar

I am newbie in Swift. I am trying to change (increase) the height of the navigation bar. Is there any obvious way?
(I tried to change it with CGRectMake but it generated a rect over the bar and i lost the back button etc.) Which is the best practice to implement?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142375/changing-the-height-of-the-navigation-bar-ios-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to increase the height of navigation bar in xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940352/how-to-increase-the-height-of-navigation-bar-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

you should not try to change navigation bar's size according to apple guideline. you should use custom navigation bar if required. hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of Inheritance Method.

1) Make a parent controller of UIViewController. Name it UIAppViewController.

```
//  UIAppViewController.swift

import UIKit

class UIAppViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    }
    func addCustomNavigationBarToView()
    {
        // Create the navigation bar
        let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 84))

        // Create a navigation item with a title
        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
        navigationItem.title = "Title"

        // Create left and right button for navigation item
        let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "saveButtonClicked:")
        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)

        // Create two buttons for the navigation item
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

        // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
        navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

        // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Note that I have made a method in which a custom Navigation Bar is added to self.view.

2) On ViewController:

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIAppViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden =  false
        self.addCustomNavigationBarToView()

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub classing UINavigationBar is also a solution.

File-New-File- iOS Source - Cocoa Touch class- Select Subclass of : UINavigationBar and Name it - CustomNavigationBar.

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

//Change here

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

//set frame.

    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize 
{
        var newSize: CGSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 70)
        return newSize
    }
```