# How do I programmatically change the height of a navigationBar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let height = CGFloat(84)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: height)
}
```

This code simply inserts space above the titleView.  A custom titleView at point (0,0) has ~20 points of space above it. A height >40 starts to run off the navBar.

Comment: 44(navigationBar height) + 20(status bar height) = 64 is the standard one.

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass UINavigationBar :

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let newSize :CGSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width,height: 84)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

Then create the navigation controller and use the initialiser to use your custom navigation bar class.

```
let nav = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass:CustomNavigationBar.self,toolbarClass: nil)
```

All existing behavior for UINavigationBar is preserved and your custom height is adopted.

OR

Like you already tried :

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let height: CGFloat = 84 //whatever height you want
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)

}
```

OR :
You can try this solution [Changing the height of the Navigation bar iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142375/changing-the-height-of-the-navigation-bar-ios-swift)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a custom view to replace the navigation bar.This is more easy and flexible. hide the navi bar and implement a custom view.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setCustomNavBarView()
    }

    func setCustomNavBarView() {
        self.navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 50)  // Set you custom width and Height
        self.navBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.view.addSubview(navBar)

    }
}
```

A simple [tutorial](https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2014/11/11/ios-app-creating-custom-nav-bar/) on how to do that:

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
        class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.    
            self.setCustomNavBarView()
    }
`func setCustomNavBarView() {
            self.navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 100)  // Set you custom width and Height
            self.navBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            self.view.addSubview(navBar)
        }
    `
```

swift 3 updated code here