# How to change UINavigationBar height?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to change the UINavigationBar height in ios 11? 
I've tried this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let height: CGFloat = 50 //whatever height you want to add to the existing height
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)

}
```

and this:

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
    }
}
```

and none of them seem to work.

Comment: You might be able to do it, but my advice would be to stop wanting to. Certainly you should not mess with the height of a navigation controller's navigation bar, because that is up to the navigation controller, which needs to be able to set it and change it on its own account.

Comment: This might be helpful for u - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142375/changing-the-height-of-the-navigation-bar-ios-swift

Comment: did you ever get this working? @dre_84w934