# Change the height of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change the `UINavigationBar` height. 
I found various solutions to solve this but none of them worked/made my app crash.

For Example [how to increase the height of navigation bar in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940352/how-to-increase-the-height-of-navigation-bar-in-xcode)

I'm using iOS 11/10/9 by the way...

Thanks (:

Comment: What error in the crash? In what line of code?

Comment: Have you used navigationController in your screen?

Comment: I added a navigation controller to the storyboard, just dragged and dropped, and about the errors:

Comment: for subview in (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
            if NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder).contains("BarBackground") {
                var subViewFrame: CGRect = subview.frame
                // subViewFrame.origin.y = -20;
                subViewFrame.size.height = 100
                subview.frame = subViewFrame
                
            }
            
        }          Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1005ff.....)

Comment: And if I run this code, I just get the Unexpectedly found nil exception for the navigationController!       -> self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 80.0) @biloshkurskyi.ss

Comment: Check this [thred](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88202)

Comment: I think you should create a custom navigation bar and use it