# How to increase the height of the navigation bar for iOS 11 and later

Tags: ios, navigationbar

The basic premise is that I want to put some images and other assets in the middle of the navigation bar and need it to be a little thicker than it is by default.  Currently it defaults to 44 points and I want to double that height.

You can find many older Q/A's about how to do this but something in the later xcode/iOS 11+ is preventing any of the other solutions to work.  The most comprehensive one is the in the link below:

[Increase the Height the most comprehensive on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940352/how-to-increase-the-height-of-navigation-bar-in-xcode)

I've tried all the answers in that chain, and many others from other Q/A's and none appear to be working any longer in iOS 11+.  I wanted to start a new question that specifically addresses this question about iOS 11 and later which there appears to be no good answers to.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am also having this same issue. Any solutions for Xcode 9 with Swift 4?