# Cannot change navigation bar item height in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

After customizing the navigation bar height bigger than the default value (44pt), I want to change the height of my right side navigation bar item button, but it's limited in 44pt. How can I make it taller? I know that in iOS 11, the button now is inside a UIBarButtonStackView, it seems we cannot change the stack view frame?

I use this code to change the width and height of the button:

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)

let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Thank you!

Comment: see this once may be it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940352/how-to-increase-the-height-of-navigation-bar-in-xcode/31940514#31940514

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I want to change the navigation bar item button, not the navigation bar, your answer is about the navigation bar.

Comment: Did you set any image in your bar button item or just the custom icon?

Comment: @MdRashedPervez I did set image for the bar button, I have updated the question.

Comment: ok..  now i see.. you can only change the width of the item not height. height will change automatically according with the height of nav bar. i will provide you the code below.

Comment: @MdRashedPervez Yes, thank you so much.

Comment: @Lucy - UIBarButtonItem only has a width property that can be set but unfortunately not a height property.based on your navigation bar height it will be increase

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I have changed the height of navigation bar, but in iOS 11, the bar button doesn't increase follow it.

Comment: change the frame of your button and check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width of navigation bar button item by using this code -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            var frame: CGRect? = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.frame
            frame?.size.width = 5  // change the width of your item bar button
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.frame = frame!
        }
        override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
            return true
        }
```

Or from storyboard -

[image]

Make sure your `Assets.xcassets` image is set as `Render As - Original` Image Just like -

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm able to change the bar button height now, work beautifully, however when I set frame.origin.y = -20 to move the button down, it doesn't work. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: button will take the center position proportionally. by the way -20 will move the button up not down.

Comment: In my case, it isn't centered. It always stick to the top

Comment: if you use image view instead of bar button item then it will be very easy for your development. You should try it.

Comment: I haven't try it before, you mean use the imageView as custom view for UIBarButtonItem right? Or just the image view? How to add image view to navigation bar?

Comment: just take a imageView or a button replace with an image. on where you put the bar button item. then you can relocate it any where in navigation bar.

Comment: I don't really get it, do you mean add the image into the navigation bar or add it into the view controller and locate it in the position I want to?

Comment: the same way you put the bar button item on top of the navigation bar. if u set imageView you should know how to chnage that image after putting it there.

Comment: By your way, I have to remove the image manually whenever app move to another view. And do the same job if the navigation bar in other view controllers have different bar buttons too. It not cool as all.

Comment: Customization was never cool. but  it creates cool things. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using subclass of UInavigationcontroller class and NavigationBar class you can achieve this.
I am sharing some code of snipt:

```
class ARVNavigationController { 
 init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
 super.init(navigationBarClass: AVNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)

viewControllers = [rootViewController] }}



class AVNavigationBar { 

 let AVNavigationBarHeight: CGFloat = 80.0


 init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
 super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 initialize()
}



init(frame: CGRect) {
super.init(frame: frame ?? CGRect.zero)
initialize()
}

func initialize() {
   transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: +AVNavigationBarHeight)
}

func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   let classNamesToReposition = ["_UINavigationBarBackground", "UINavigationItemView", "UINavigationButton"]
   for view: UIView? in subviews() {
       if classNamesToReposition.contains(NSStringFromClass(view.self)) {
         let bounds: CGRect = self.bounds()
         let frame: CGRect? = view?.frame
         frame?.origin.y = bounds.origin.y + CGFloat(AVNavigationBarHeight)
         frame?.size.height = bounds.size.height - 20.0
         view?.frame = frame ?? CGRect.zero
       }
   }
}

 func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    return .topAttached
 }
```

}

Comment: That if condition is used to check what elements in UINavigationController you want to change like _UINavigationBarBackground
 UINavigationItemView

Comment: I tried to print out the subview class name, but there is no UINavigationItemView or UINavigationButton.