# how to add image as the title on large navigation bar in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I need to make an image as the title of the LARGE navigation bar. I use this function below to set an image in the normal navigation bar ( i mean the small one)

```
func setUpNavigationBarTitleImage() {

    let navController = navigationController!

    let image = UIImage(named: "2-1 H Logo Home.png")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
    let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

    let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - image.size.width / 2
    let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - image.size.height / 2

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```

but if i use that code, the image seems not in the center of the navigation bar like this

[image]

I need the image to be more in the center like the picture below

[image]

Comment: make Custom navigation bar.

Comment: I hope help this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31940514/3752143

Comment: @MitulMarsoniya OP already has a large navigation bar, they are having a problem with the placement of an added subview.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
func setUpNavigationBarTitleImage() {

    let navController = navigationController!

    let image = UIImage(named: "2-1 H Logo Home.png")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
    let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.center = navController.navigationBar.center

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```